# form does not posting the data of filtered field?

Tags: php, html, ajax

i am fetching categories and their sub-categories from the database.
and filtering the sub-categories after selecting the category bu using dropdown.
after selecting when i submit the form, the value of the sub-category is 0, form does not posting the selected value.

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_POST) && $_POST['submit'] == "Add")
    {
        extract($_POST);
        $scat_id = $regions['scat_id'];
        echo $sqlpa = "INSERT INTO products(mcat_id, scat_id)VALUES('$mcat_id', '$scat_id')";   
            $resultpa = mysql_query($sqlpa);

    }
  ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    function getregions(mcat_id) {
      if (mcat_id=="") {
         document.getElementById("region").innerHTML="";
         return;
      }
      if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {// code for IE7+, Firefox, Chrome, Opera, Safari
         xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
      } else {// code for IE6, IE5
         xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
      }
      xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function() {
        if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200) {
           document.getElementById("region").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
        }
      }
    xmlhttp.open("GET","getregions.php?mcat_id="+mcat_id,true);
    xmlhttp.send();
    }
    </script>
    <form action="" method="post" name="p_add" id="p_add">
     <table>
```

```
      <tr>
         <td>Select Category</td>
         <td><select name="mcat_id" id="mcat_id" onchange="getregions(this.value);">
                <option value="">Select</option>
                 <?php 
              if(!empty($resultm)) {
                 foreach($resultm as $rm) {
             ?>
                <option value="<?php echo $rm['mcat_id']; ?>"><?php echo $rm['mcat_name'];?> (<?php echo $rm['mcat_id']; ?>)</option>
                 <?php 
                         }
                      }
                 ?>
           </select>
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
           <td>Select Sub-Category</td>
           <td>
             <div id="region">
           <select name="scat_id" id="scat_id">
             <option value="">Please Select</option>
           </select>
         </div>
           </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>&nbsp;</td>
            <td><input type="submit" name="submit" value="Add" /></td>
         </tr>       
   </table>
 </form>
```

-->this page is getregions.php    where filtering is done:

```
<?php 
   include "../conn.php";
   $mcat_id=$_GET['mcat_id'];
   $sql = "SELECT * FROM sub_category WHERE mcat_id = '".$mcat_id."'";
   $res = mysql_query($sql);
   while($row = mysql_fetch_array($res)) {
    $rec[] = $row ;
   }
?>
<select name="scat_id" id="scat_id">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
<?php 
foreach($rec as $regions) {
?>
   <option value="<?php echo $regions['scat_id'];?>"><?php echo $regions['scat_name'];?></option>
<?php 
}
?>
</select>
```

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the [red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is](http://goo.gl/vFWnC) good tutorial.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

just before the insert query, i need to write

```
 $scat_id = $_post['scat_id'];
```

this will get the posted value.